# position the pop up

Tags: javascript, css

I have several boxes (more than 100) that will be created dynamically in different positions on the screen. Upon clicking each box, I want a slide in pop up with the details.

I want its position to slide in near each boxes. I have done that, but, if some boxes are near the browser window end on the right side, half of the pop up gets hidden in the window.

I want those pop-ups to display fully before the window (as like in excel).

my javascript code for postioning;

```
function centerPopup(comp_id, top, left) {    
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": top + 70,
        "left": left + 223
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly it's not the overlap with other boxes but losing half the box on the edges of the screen? This sounds like you're using the edge of the window to set the position of the box but you aren't accounting for the width of the box itself. Make sure to get the width of the current box divided by two and subtract this from the max window size. This will position the right edge of your box at the right side of the window (if you imagine a box rendered at the far right of the screen).

Hopefully I'm interpreting your question correctly.

Comment: Yes U understood my problem,Thanks for your answer!but the width is set it to auto in css while creating those dynamic boxes.How can I get the width in javascript?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already you can get the window's properties with $(window) such as $(window).width() This might be a better reference: http://api.jquery.com/width/ There are several different global objects for window, screen, scrollTop, etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: my each box is dynamically created.If i try to get the box width using: var b = $("div[id *= 'window']").width(); Am getting only the same width for all boxes,if i tried div[id *= 'window22'], i get the width of 22 box.How it will recognize the id on each click

Comment: Wherever you are handling your click events for each box you can reference the current box clicked as $(this) and then chain functions onto it, such as $(this).width() If this doesn't help you fully please post a greater selection of your code so we can look at it and assist you better :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are appearing underneath another element, try adding a higher `z-index` to the style of the popup box. that will allow it to appear *over* something else with a lower `z-index`.

I'd need more code, or an example (use jsfiddle.net) to really see what's going on

Comment: @iight- I am agree with you...:)

Z-index is used to show pop up which appears underneath of dialogs...I too have faced this problem..when i set z-index, I got the result.